# I cannot click an Xpath element - Selenium ( v. 4.2 or higher) - Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, click

I am trying to draw data from a government website related to air quality and other statistical data. I am trying to automate the data retrieval process. However, following the entry into the data drawing page by 'Tiklama2' I was not able to click any elements.

```
Tiklama = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dropdown3-contentDataDowloadNew"]/div/div/div/div/span[3]')
Tiklama.click()
```

The above code just doesn't work...

The code is below and there is no need to hide the URL or anything:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.havaizleme.gov.tr/")
driver.fullscreen_window()
time.sleep(10)

Tiklama2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Harita"]/div[1]/a[5]')
Tiklama2.click()
time.sleep(100)


Tiklama = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dropdown3-contentDataDowloadNew"]/div/div/div/div/span[3]')
Tiklama.click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: driver.quit() was added for the completeness of the code...

Comment: _I was not able to click any elements_ Don't make us guess what "not able to click" means exactly.  Please post the full error traceback message.

Comment: Could you kindly verify if the provided URL is accurate? I am currently experiencing difficulty accessing it.

Comment: THe URL: https://www.havaizleme.gov.tr/

Comment: The page entered with Tiklama2: https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/MaRJha53p0hQew    There is no problem here....I can click the element on the left side circled in red

Comment: And the element I am trying to click: https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/vL_roduzJzNPaA

Comment: In fact I have not been able to click anything on that page...

Comment: That xpath finds a `<span>` element.  Span elements generally aren't clickable.  Maybe you're actually looking for something that is **inside** that span?

Comment: Thank you for the hint ...I'll check. Thank you again.

Comment: span's 'unselectable' value is 'on'!!!.... I think this is it.... I'll let you know.!

Comment: I tried to turn of the unselectable attribute with: login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Harita"]/div[1]/a[5]')
login.click()
time.sleep(180)

selects = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@unselectable, 'on']")
for select in selects:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('unselectable', 'off'), select")
selects.click()

Comment: However it gives the following error: Xpath is not a valid expression

Comment: The element is as follows: <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-clear-value k-i-close" title="Tümünü Seç" data-event="all" role="button" tabindex="-1" style="background-position: -32px -32px;"></span>

Comment: Full xPath of element: /html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div/div/div/span[3]